# shell iterate through custom list of numbers

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix

I can iterate through evenly-spaced sequences of numbers using `seq` or a c-style for loop:

```
$ for (( i = 1; i < 6 ; ++i)); do echo $i ; done

1
2
3
4
5

$ for i in $(seq 1 5); do echo $i; done
1
2
3
4
```

I want to generate an irregular sequence, `1 2 4 4.25 4.5 5`. What is a simple way to iterate through these numbers in a shell loop?

Comment: You can use: `for i in 1 2 4 4.25 4.5 5; do echo $i; done`

Comment: Or `for i in $(cat file_containing_my_numbers); do echo $i; done`

Comment: Thanks. That was easier than I expected.

Comment: Is there a pattern to your pattern? For instance does this irregularity happens every four counts? Does it just happen once? Does it always happen or does it happen at random? If it only happens once does it always happen after the same counts? These are questions you have to answer first if you truly want to "generate" the sequence.

Comment: There is no pattern to my pattern

Comment: Then you are probably looking for RANDOM that has been seeded. http://viralpatel.net/blogs/generate-random-number-unix-shell-script/ or if you want random in a certain range: awk -v min=5 -v max=10 'BEGIN{srand(); print int(min+rand()*(max-min+1))}' : http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/140750/generate-random-numbers-in-specific-range

Comment: I am not looking for a stochastic approach. The comments above answered my question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you are using aubhava's approach, you can also display decimal places in your output:

```
for i in 1 2 4 4.25 4.5 5; do
    printf '%0.02f\n' $i
done
```

output:

```
1.00
2.00
4.00
4.25
4.50
5.00
```